# asp.net jquery ajax page reload issue

Tags: asp.net

We are loading a child page in the parent page parent.aspx as follows -
 $("#result").load("child.aspx");

child.aspx consists of an asp:LinkButton.

Problem -
OnClick of asp:LinkButton is causing Child.aspx to be opened instead of being embedded in parent.aspx as before the click event.

Expected -
Child.aspx should remain embedded in Parent.aspx onClick of the asp:LinkButton

NOTE - On debug we observe that first the Page_Load method is first invoked followed by the onClick event handler.

Comment: Sorry, but this is as clear as mud!

Comment: If the *child.aspx* should always be shown as embedded in the parent page, maybe consider turning it into a User Control (**.ascx* file).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you're loading the child page into the div, you're alsing loading the form element for `child.aspx` as well, making it so you have two forms on the page now.  And I'll bet that that form is set to post to child.aspx.  So when you click the linkbutton, it submits the form and directs the entire window to child.aspx.

If you want to embed an entire page inside another page, you may want to use an iframe.